# Check file count in a common subdirectory from all the directories

Tags: linux, unix

I have a list of directories and all the directories have a few common sub directories. I would like to know if there are any files in one of the common sub directories in unix.

```
abc
 incoming
 staging
def
 incoming
 staging
ghi
 incoming
 staging
```

In the above structure, I would like to get a list of directories where the `incoming` folder has a file.

Comment: Also, welcome to StackOverflow. This site provides a forum for programmers to get programming help from other programmers. There's an expectation that for any task, you'll have done a basic amount of effort to solve it yourself, and you'll show your efforts in your question, so that we can help identify problems, and suggest improvements. Have a look at [How To Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), and see if you can come up with an [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) so that we can be confident with our answers.

Comment: And if you just want to list files in the `incoming` folders, use a glob. `/path/to/{abc,def,ghi}/incoming/*` should match any files in any incoming folders in a number of shells. You'd need to show tell us more of your requirements, describe your platform and show your work in order to get anything but random guesses as answers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your questions is not really clear so I assume **you want to check file count for all the common directory incoming.**

This bash script would print all the **incoming** directory paths and their respective file counts.

```
#!/bin/bash

ROOT_DIR=<PATH OF THE DIRECTORIES>
TARGET_DIR=incoming

for i in $( ls -d $ROOT_DIR/*/*/ );
do
  if [[ "$i" == *"$TARGET_DIR"* ]];
  then
    echo "$i"
    ls $i | wc -l
  fi
done
```

Comment: Victor, the OP has mentioned he's using "Unix" in comments, but he hasn't mentioned Linux (except the tag) or the availability of a `bash` shell, which your answer depends on. When providing an answer that is more limited in scope than the question, it's a really good idea to identify such limitations up front, so that a newbie questioner doesn't get stuck with, for example, the fact that `/bin/sh` in Solaris/Irix/AIX/BSD doesn't have a `[[` command.

Comment: Thanks Victor, I am looking for the exact solution.